# Java Socket closed error httpclient

Tags: java, sockets, synchronization, client, desktop

I am working on desktop application that is continuously syncing the data from desktop to server.

The connection is breaking in between, I have got it reconnected but its not syncing after re-connection.

In the below code i check for the connection

```
RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().
                  setConnectTimeout(timeout * 1000).
                  setConnectionRequestTimeout(timeout * 1000).
                  setSocketTimeout(timeout * 1000).build();
        httpGetMethod.setConfig(config);

        client = clientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).build();
response = client.execute(httpGetMethod, context);
```

If the connection had been successful, then I have the below code to start sync,

```
if (syncThread == null)
        syncThread = new SyncThread(this, userAccount);
    syncThread.setUserAccount(XGlobal.dbUtil.getUserAccount());
    syncThread.startSync();
    if (!XGlobal.downloading)
            this.syncViewLauncher.setDefautConnection();
    this.changeIcon(true);          
    syncCompletionService.submit(syncThread);
```

Comment: How are you reconnecting it?

Comment: By calling method setupconnection again in which the reconnection happens